# Average Reward (On policy control) Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In Sutton and Barto [Book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), under section **10.3. Average Reward: A New Problem Setting for Continuing Tasks**, what is the use of subtracting reward and the average reward? What are they trying to solve here, I understood what an average reward is, but failed to understand why it is being subtracted from the reward at each time step. (shown in the images below)[image: Average Reward]

where average reward is given by [image]

Answer (score 1):

Section 10.3 presents a nondiscounted continual learning setting.

If we use the rewards as is (without subtracting the empirical mean reward at time step t), then the return and value function can grow without bound.

On the other hand, the differential return $G_t$ as you screenshotted above converges to zero in the limit of $t$.